# И снова Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php

Помогите решить проблему! Вот пример кода:

```
`<? session_start();?>
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {if($_FILES['image_load']['size']>1048576){
$hasError = true;
echo '<style>#image_load{border:1px solid red;}</style>';
$_SESSION['msg1'] = 'Image exceeds 1 MB!';
}
else {
$img = $_FILES['image_load'];
}if(!isset($hasError))  {
die(header("Location: index.php"));
}
else {
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'Error! Incorrectly filled fields!';
}
die(header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
}
?>`
```

Выводит сообщение Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\OSPanel\domains...
Как я понимаю, это проблема с буферизацией? Как её решить? Слышал можно с помощью ob_start()?

Comment: Сначала проверьте код в вопросе - символы точно все те, что, есть в файле?

Comment: Ошибка про то, что до отправки заголовков (либо до старта сессии, по примеру не ясно где начало документа) был некий вывод на страницу. через echo скорее всего.

Comment: @3 Darin этот варнинг очень хорошо описан в интернете. как и буферизация вывода. ДЖАСТ ГУГЛ ИТ!

Comment: Собственно у вас сначала идет `echo` (4 строка), а потом, ниже, отправка хидеров.

Comment: То, что это происходит из-за echo я понял. Но как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Тут что-то происходит с echo и header

Comment: @rjhdby Что в данной ситуации нужно сделать?

Comment: @3Darin прочитать текст ошибки. Сначала отправляются все хидеры и только потом можно что-то выводить на экран. Решать можно либо изменением порядка операторов, либо включением буферизации в самом начале и сбросом буферов после отработки всех `header`

Comment: @rjhdby Ок. Можете на примере моего кода показать как это будет выглядеть?